# how to connect arduino ethernet to internet using my laptop's wifi connection

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

This is the image of ipconfig from cmd.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has previously worked for me when sharing an internet connection:

1. Right Click on the WiFi icon on the task bar, select open network sharing center.
2. Select change adapter settings on the left
3. Right click your WiFi Adapter, select the sharing tab.
4. Select Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection.
5. Set the connection to share to Ethernet.
6. Connect your Ethernet Shield to the Ethernet port on your computer.

Another route that I have heard of, but have not tried, is to bridge the two connections together. Follow steps 1 and 2 above, then do these steps:

1. Press down the control key, and select both your Ethernet and WiFi adapters.
2. Right click one of them, and select bridge connections.

I cannot confirm the second method works, but the first one worked fine for me.

You might need a crossover cable, but these can be easily made using a normal Ethernet cable. [Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ethernet-crossover-cable/) is a good example.

If the Ethernet board has autosensing, then you do not need to crossover cable. I could not find out if it is necessary, so trial and error would be the best bet for that. Try Ethernet cable first, then try crossover.

Comment: Thanks for the solution....Second one didn't work for me as I had already tried it...Will try to do the first one...but right now node-red is helping to fill the gap.

Comment: Just look out for the possibility of needing a crossover cable